# How to add database environment variables to Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, environment-variables

I want to add my database environment variables to a `.env` file and use that file in my Javascript program in order to create a connection to my database using Node.js.

So here is my database info which I use to create connection with:

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "my password",
  database: "mydatabase"
});
```

Then I try to check if I am connected to my database using these lines:

(It should print "Connected!").

```
con.connect(function(err) {   
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});
```

I want to put the first block of code in another file and `require` that file in my Node.js program.

How should I do this? How should I `require` the file? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using [dotenv package](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv).

Taken straight from the readme:

1. As early as possible in your application, require and configure dotenv.

   `require('dotenv').config()`
2. Create a `.env` file in the root directory of your project. Add
   environment-specific variables on new lines in the form of `NAME=VALUE`. For example:

   `DB_HOST=localhost
   DB_USER=root
   DB_PASS=s1mpl3`
3. Usage (`process.env` now has the keys and values you defined in your `.env` file.)

   `var db = require('db')
   db.connect({
     host: process.env.DB_HOST,
     username: process.env.DB_USER,
     password: process.env.DB_PASS
   })`

**NOTE**: Make sure your `.gitignore` has an entry to **ignore** `.env` files.

Comment: That was great! Thank you.

Comment: I'm just not sure about this line:
`var db = require ('db')`
Can you explain it, please?  What does db refer to?

Comment: @ZahraGolpa `db` in this example is almost equivalent to `var con = mysql.createConnection({...});`.  It is a different way to organize the code and instantiating the connection to the database.

Comment: I got it. Thank you ;)

Comment: Re: .gitignore
What if I want to use github pages to deploy a demo of this app? I'm creating a html/js project for school, and although it's above and beyond what I'm required to do, I wanted to add extra functionality and include a firebase firestore db connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a module called [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) which will load an environments variables defined in a `.env` file or any file you specify. You would then load the `.env` in two ways:

1. In the main script file, call `require('dotenv').config()`
2. Via npm script: `"dev": "node -r dotenv/config app.js"`

Either works, but you do not want to commit `.env` to source control. Always keep sensitive credentials out. You can create a an `.env.example` to alert new users the required variables.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help  @fransiscoMateo

Answer (score 0):

**Using dotenv package. Install dotenv package.**

> npm i dotenv

**Create a new .env file in project root directory.**

> touch .env

**Add environment variables to .env file**

```
API_HOST=HOST-PLACEHOLDER-URL
API_KEY=TOP-SECRET
APP_NAME=node_crud
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:RIjL2Uw/Wdve+HJEvRNp6LHhzoHtLbplQcUp60CBIvs=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost
LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=node_restapi
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
PORT = 5000
```

**Add config/database.js file**

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const mysql = require('mysql');

// configraration with env. 
dotenv.config();
module.exports = mysql.createConnection({
host: process.env.DB_HOST,
user: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD, 
database: process.env.DB_DATABASE 
});
```

**config/database.js connect with app.js file**

```
// Database Connection
const conn = require('./config/database');
// Shows Mysql Connect
conn.connect((err) =>{
if(err) throw err;
console.log('Mysql Connected with App...');
});
```

---

[image]

- A **.env** file is needed for a clean separation of environment-specific configurations.
- The **dotenv packaged** is used to read a .env file at runtime containing environment variables and append them on the **process.env** object.
- Creating an example for a **.env** file to document the mandatory variables speeds up project setup time.
- Never commit a **.env** file to version control.